# Is it good practice to use SMTP (with phpmailer) to send emails with PHP.?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I've just started using PhpMailer, so I've had to decide if I was going to use SMTP, sendmail, qmail... I've always used the simple mail() function in PHP, and never really thought about it.

Is one method better, more reliable, simpler, or more appropriate for a specific task.? (massmail, attachment, etc...)

I'm developping on my PC (wamp) and websites are always on Unix server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing on MSWindows, then it's unusual to have a local MTA with a CLI interface - i.e. you probably have to use SMTP. Using SMTP does not mean that you can't use the local MTA, nor does using a local MTA mean that you can't send emails to the world.

I would recommend using a local MTA (or at least one on your network) - it provides you with far greater control over managing your email policy (e.g. SPF, adding signatures etc). However if you are developing on MSWindows, then you don't want to be running significantly different code on your production site - so develop using an SMTP connection, but using your own MTA.